Git clone through SSH key cannot find private repository with access
I have access to the repository via the UI, I can download via zip but I can't clone it via SSH. I can clone other repos on different orgs though. I have tried to re create my ssh keys but not luck.
This is the verbose git clone. What else can I do? Also tried removing all references of github on macos Keychain
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi fcpauldiaz! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'  git clone git@github.com:makerkit/next-supabase-saas-kit-turbo.git
Cloning into 'next-supabase-saas-kit-turbo'...
OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/config line 3: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/fcpauldiaz-GitHub type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/fcpauldiaz-GitHub-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-62e40f88
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-62e40f88
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 4 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/fcpauldiaz-GitHub ED25519 SHA256:OGa2kzXWfefW5juNUQ+PkajoyUcVmpNk31LxJZ8Y9/o explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: Generated by Sourcetree on macOS for fcpauldiaz-GitHub ED25519 SHA256:oUrDTBd9ndT7tARv/DxETyL9VFt9m3ZFw3H9yDpt22U agent
debug1: Will attempt key: Generated by Sourcetree on macOS for fcpauldiaz-GitHub ED25519 SHA256:ig0SHX756P0ZohQgBnYbGTNPT0Ru/FSxFuOEdw/9UP8 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: Generated by Sourcetree on macOS for fcpauldiaz-GitHub ED25519 SHA256:Rut7OveQETkO2yX4u1I0EA6LKmstG53+dXZndhBPBNI agent
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/fcpauldiaz-GitHub ED25519 SHA256:OGa2kzXWfefW5juNUQ+PkajoyUcVmpNk31LxJZ8Y9/o explicit agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/fcpauldiaz-GitHub ED25519 SHA256:OGa2kzXWfefW5juNUQ+PkajoyUcVmpNk31LxJZ8Y9/o explicit agent
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.113.3]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env GIT_PROTOCOL = "version=2"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8"
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'makerkit/next-supabase-saas-kit-turbo.git'
debug1: pledge: fork
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
ERROR: Repository not found.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2296, received 2496 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 13223.9, received 14375.8
debug1: Exit status 1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I have tried to re create the SSH keys, the public key is already uploaded to Github and I can clone other repos, except this one private in another org (I do have access in the UI). I do not want to do it via https, only ssh
this is the .ssh/config
Host github.com
        HostName github.com
        User fcpauldiaz
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile /Users/fcpauldiaz/.ssh/fcpauldiaz-GitHub
        UseKeychain yes
        AddKeysToAgent yes
# ----------------------------```

